# How do I connect the hair properly?

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, bones, error, pose-mode

So I have the bones connected properly, from hair to base, but when I go to Pose Mode and click on the neck bone to move, the head moves and not the hair. The hair model stays still even though I have the bones connected properly. Can someone please help me solve this issue? [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In object mode select the hair mesh, shift select the armature, go to pose mode, select an appropriate bone (head or hair) and press Ctrl P > Bone.