# Why isn't the hair moving right?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, error, pose-mode

I figured out how to make the hair model move by a friendly user, but now my issue is how it's moving. The hair moves along with my base, however its movement is off timing. I can provide file to my model if anyone wants to check it out for themselves? It would help me a lot!

[How do I connect the hair properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/247422/138463)  <-- old link

[http://%22C:%5CUsers%5Cderam%5CDownloads%5Cmodel%20stuff%5Cnew%20model.blend1%22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUWyt.jpg)

[image]

Comment: it would really help if you....provide the link of your old question and provide your blend file to check out

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)