# Join headphones to a model

Tags: modeling, parent, pose-mode

I downloaded the free Vincent model at the blender official library and i wanted to modify a few things of him. Adding some headphones to the model it's being a big headache. I model the headphones and try to join (ctrl+j) the head with them, but when i change the pose the headphones doesnt move (also joining those parts i lose the colour of the headphones).

I try also to add a parenting system (ctrl+p) but i don't know if i'm doing it well, after doing it, when i change the pose, the headphones doesn't move.

How can i do this? I just want to place de headphones there, during the animation they aren't goint to move from his ears.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247422/how-do-i-connect-the-hair-properly/247426#247426

Comment: ¡¡¡¡Thank you so much!!!!